# How to properly update a datatable while inside a loop

Tags: c#

In my below code I'm comparing values (email addresses) in my Arrarylist (called emails) with values in my Datatable (called dtResult).  I was hoping to be able to remove rows from the datatable if it has an email address that is found in the arraylist but I'm starting to think I'm better off creating a new datatable that does not have those rows instead (I just don't know how to do that).  Obviously my code below bombs after a row is deleted because it loses its place in the foreach loop.  How can I fix this?

Thanks.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtResult.Rows)
{
  var tmpl = row[3];
  for (int x = 0; x < emails.Count; x++)  //emails is an ArrayList of email addresses
  {
    string one = emails[x].ToString().ToUpper();
    string two = tmpl.ToString().ToUpper();
    //compare datatable value to arraylist value..
    if (one == two)
    {
      //if they are equal then I want to remove them (or maybe create a new datatable??)
      dtResult.Rows.Remove(row);
      dtResult.AcceptChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an expensive process and anything you can do to help speed it up is good.  If your dtResult has no dups, remove the matched value from emails when you find a match and break out of the inner loop.   Make sure emails is converted to uppercase ahead of time, instead of on each pass.  Why not use foreach in the inner loop?

I saw a suggestion elsewhere that moving AcceptChanges outside the loop will make this work without the "foreach" -> "backward for" loop refactoring suggested below, but have not tried it.

Comment: You should probably use a List<EmailType> instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: @Steve:  It would be a good idea to only call `AcceptChanges` once, but it still wouldn't work at all without the backward loop.  You can't add or remove from a collection in the middle of a `foreach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to loop through the `DataTable` backward:

```
for (int i = dtResult.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = dtResult.Rows[i];
    // ...
}
```

You also might want to consider whether you can just mark the [row state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) on those rows as deleted (and then observe that status later) instead of actually removing them from the table.

Answer (score 2):

You could go through the DataTable in reverse

```
for(int i  = dtResult.Rows.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
     foreach(object email in emails)
     {
          if(email.ToString().ToUpper() == dtResult[i].ToString().ToUpper())
          {
               dtResult.Rows.Remove(dtResult.Rows[i]);
               dtResult.AcceptChanges();
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it in two steps?

I didn't try this, so let me know how it goes.

```
var deleteRows = new List<DataRow>();
```

then in your loop, instead of deleting the row right away, just add the row to your list:

```
deleteRows.Add(row);
```

and after you loop through your database, you loop through the deleteRows list and delete each row one by one.